# Ищу помощь с вложенным запросом MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Нужно расположить блоки в правильной последовательности. 
"Экспресс курс по основам SQL" с минимальным количеством примеров, поэтому возникли трудности со связью между таблицами.

[image: Задача]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select Название, 
       (select SUM(ПроданоБилетов) from Flights where ТипСамолета= types.Номер) 
from PlaneTypes as types;
```

Comment: SELECT ТипСамолета, (SELECT SUM(ПроданоБилетов) FROM Flights WHERE ТипСамолета = types.Номер) FROM PlaneTypes AS types; <br/> Поменял местами "ТипСамолета=" и types.Номер, так как "=" относится к ТипСамолета.. Но, в общем, решение не принято. Может еще как-то "название" нужно использовать?

Comment: @iListo обновил ответ. Попробуйте так

Comment: Подзапрос-то тут нафига?

Comment: @Akina потому, что у ТС в проверяющей системе блоки с текстом, которые похоже надо мышкой выставить в нужном порядке. И куска с `group by` там нет. Такая вот дурацкая система.

Comment: Блин, это у него задание - расположить куски кода в правильном порядке??? во дурь-то...

Comment: @Akina вроде того. При том, самого правильно порядка там даже нет =\

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT PlaneTypes.Название, SUM(Flights.ПроданоБилетов) ПроданоБилетов
FROM PlaneTypes
LEFT JOIN Flights ON PlaneTypes.НомерТипа = Flights.ТипСамолёта
GROUP BY PlaneTypes.Название
```

> Нужно расположить блоки в правильной последовательности.

Не нужно. Нет такой буквы в задании.